# std::string allocate memory 2 times for 1 string

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, allocation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void* operator new(size_t size) {
    std::cout << "Allocated: " << size << " Bytes\n";
    return malloc(size);
}

void operator delete(void* var) {
    std::cout << "Deleted\n";
    free(var);
}

int main() {
    std::string name0 = "Ahmed Zaki Marei";
    //std::string name1 = "Lara Mohammed";

    std::cout << name0 << "\n";
    //std::cout << name1 << "\n";
}
```

When I try to run this code it gives me this output:

```
Allocated: 8 Bytes
Allocated: 32 Bytes
Ahmed Zaki Marei
Deleted
Deleted
```

why does it allocate 8 bytes first then allocate 32 bytes?
could anyone explain it, please? thx! :)

Comment: Only one allocation of 17 bytes [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba28e3afec798306) with gcc/clang.

Comment: I wonder if it is different when compiling in Debug mode vs Release mode?

Comment: In any case this is implementation-specific. And since we can't look at Microsoft's library code, we can only guess...

Comment: @AMZ Try putting a breakpoint in `operator new` to see why its called.

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner already tried it, it's the same

Comment: Sub in your own allocator if you no like :)

Comment: @François Andrieux : it's calling it self again "when it reach the closing bracket of the new operator function"

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but don’t use any C++ standard library functions inside your own `operator new` and `operator delete`. There is no guarantee that `operator<<`, for example, won’t allocate any memory. It’s okay to use C functions, so `printf` is safe.

Comment: I looked at stack trace -- this is MS STL behavior in `Debug` mode, smth to do with `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL`. Everything is fine in `Release`.

Comment: @C.M. : In release mode it allocates 32 bytes once, still the same.
std::string supposed to be 24 bytes cuz when i try to "std::cout << sizeof(std::string) << std::endl;" it prints 24

Comment: `sizeof(std::string)` is how many bytes get allocated *on the stack* to hold the string object; it's an entirely different figure from the number of bytes that get allocated *on the heap* by the new-operator to hold the characters that the string object points to.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Alright, If you're right then i think if i tried to "std::cout << sizeof(name0) << std::endl;" it's supposed to give me 32, but it give me 24.
is the "sizeof()" function just prints the type size or the actual size that stored in the memory?

Comment: @AMZ `sizeof()` prints the size of the type, as calculated at compile-time.  But note that the `std::string` class has the ability to allocate an arbitrarily large amount of RAM from the heap (e.g. if you want you can create a megabytes-long string); that allocation is done separately and does not change the value returned by `sizeof(whateverStringObject)`; `sizeof()` does not include heap-allocations as they are not part of the object at compile time.

Comment: Btw `sizeof(std::string)` is not required to return 32 (or any other particular value); what it returns depends on how the `std::string` class was implemented in the version of the STL that your compiler is using, and it's entirely up to the authors of that class how big they want their `std::string` objects to be.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thx, That really helps ! :)

Comment: @DevSolar is there any particular reason you "cant look at Microsofts library code and can only guess"? https://github.com/microsoft/STL/tree/master/stl

Comment: @MikeVine: Didn't know about that, thanks.

Comment: The `operator new` overload will take effect for everything, not just `std::string`'s memory, of course. What is your proof that the 2nd allocation is for the `std::string`, and not for something else that the C++ library creates, when the program starts?

Comment: Output streams like `std::cout` maintain a stream buffer which is initialised during program startup, (potentially) dynamically resized during any output operation, and released as the program terminates.  Any such initialisation, resizing, and release of stream buffers uses operators `new` and `delete` by default.   Since you have overridden the global `operator new()` and corresponding `operator delete()`, they may be called in associated with the stream buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As C.M. already pointed out in the comments: *this is MS STL behavior in Debug mode, smth to do with _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL. Everything is fine in Release.*

Was curious so I tested it myself and the stack reads this on first breakpoint in `new`:

```
operator new(unsigned int size)
std::_Default_allocate_traits::_Allocate(const unsigned int _Bytes)
std::_Allocate<8,std::_Default_allocate_traits,0>(const unsigned int _Bytes)
std::allocator<std::_Container_proxy>::allocate(const unsigned int _Count)
std::_Container_proxy_ptr12<std::allocator<std::_Container_proxy>>::_Container_proxy_ptr12<std::allocator<std::_Container_proxy>>(std::allocator<std::_Container_proxy> & _Al_, std::_Container_base12 & _Mycont)
std::string::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>(const char * const _Ptr)
main()
```

Let us look at the `basic_string` constructor:

```
    basic_string(_In_z_ const _Elem* const _Ptr) : _Mypair(_Zero_then_variadic_args_t{}) {
        auto&& _Alproxy = _GET_PROXY_ALLOCATOR(_Alty, _Getal());
        _Container_proxy_ptr<_Alty> _Proxy(_Alproxy, _Mypair._Myval2);
```

and what that `_Container_proxy_ptr` really is:

```
#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 0
#define _GET_PROXY_ALLOCATOR(_Alty, _Al) _Fake_allocator()
template <class _Alloc>
using _Container_proxy_ptr = _Fake_proxy_ptr_impl;
#else // _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 0
#define _GET_PROXY_ALLOCATOR(_Alty, _Al) static_cast<_Rebind_alloc_t<_Alty, _Container_proxy>>(_Al)
template <class _Alloc>
using _Container_proxy_ptr = _Container_proxy_ptr12<_Rebind_alloc_t<_Alloc, _Container_proxy>>;
#endif // _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 0
```

It is `_Container_proxy_ptr12` (eventually calling `.allocate(1)`) in Debug
and `_Fake_proxy_ptr_impl` (doing nothing) in Release.