# Why does "unordered_map" allocating memory 2 times?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, heap-memory, allocation, unordered-map

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

#define print(x) std::cout << x
#define println(x) std::cout << x << std::endl

void* operator new(size_t size) {
    println("Allocated: " << size << " Bytes of memory");
    return malloc(size);
}

void operator delete(void* object) {
    println("Deleted !");
    free(object);
}

template<typename T>
T input(const char* string) {
    print(string);
    T temp;
    std::cin >> temp;
    return temp;
}

int main() {
    //println(sizeof(const char*) * 4 + sizeof(int) * 4);
    std::unordered_map<const char*, int> ages;
    ages.reserve(3);
    ages["Ahmed"] = 17;
    std::initializer_list<const char*> names = {"Asem", "Khalid"};
    int i = 17;
    for (const char* name : names) {
        ages[name] = i;
        i++;
    }
    for (auto age : ages) {
        println(age.first << " is " << age.second << " years old!");
    }
}
```

When I try to run this code "in release mode" it gives me this output:

```
Allocated: 16 Bytes of memory
Allocated: 64 Bytes of memory
Allocated: 16 Bytes of memory
Allocated: 16 Bytes of memory
Allocated: 16 Bytes of memory
Khalid is 18 years old!
Asem is 17 years old!
Ahmed is 17 years old!
Deleted !
Deleted !
Deleted !
Deleted !
Deleted !
```

I tried to debug to code and I notice that when this line:

```
std::unordered_map<const char*, int> ages;
```

gets executed it allocates memory to times, Output:

```
Allocated: 16 Bytes of memory
Allocated: 64 Bytes of memory
```

Why is that happening ?!, Btw when i try to run it in debug mode it gives me more than 2 allocations :/
EDIT: my platform is Windows 10 pro x64 and I'm using msvc

Comment: You could put further print statements between your lines in `main` to see which statement is responsible for which allocation.

Comment: Also, the additional allocations in debug mode are explained in your previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63496083/stdstring-allocate-memory-2-times-for-1-string).

Comment: @cigien yes i know that, my main question was about why is that happening in release mode

Comment: @AMZ: If you're new to C++, you shouldn't *care* about the memory allocation pattern of `unordered_map`. Those details do not and should not matter to you. It's happening because your implementation of `unordered_map` needs that memory to do its job, and that's all you need to know at present. If you want to know the details, then you need to learn how to write a hash table.

Comment: @NicolBolas yes you're right, but i was wondering why is that happening and I need to know that because I love knowing the small details about anything and try to optimize it or even implementing my own data structure that might do the same thing but without allocating memory.
I already did that with vectors, arrays etc...
I really love going deep on c++ and understand how things really works.

Comment: If you "love knowing the small details about anything", then using the debugger and inspecting the stack trace will give you plenty of small details about everything that has happened, and why. This is precisely what a debugger is for.

Comment: @KamolHasan no it's a different thing + I'm the person who asked this question so no. I believe it's a different thing

Comment: @AMZ, the best thing would be to learn about hash tables - this will help you understand the memory allocations. but learning about hash tables will take a little longer than learning about vectors, so be prepared to study it for a week or so to get the basics.

Comment: @Elliott Ok i'll learn it, Thx btw :)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you're right but I'm not able to understand everything on the stack trace or how to use it and trace things correctly !.
This is why i came to ask here.
I'll try to use it more in my life to learn more about it.
Thx btw :)

Comment: I think on Visual Studio an unordered_map is implemented something like a vector containing lists. The vector is needed for the hash; the list contains the elements. A list element needs to be allocated each time.

Answer (score -1):

You can print internal stack trace on memory allocations with dbghelp library. This will get you deep into stl where unordered_map allocates memory.

````
#pragma comment(lib, "Dbghelp.lib")

using namespace std;


#define TRACE_MAX_STACK_FRAMES 1024
#define TRACE_MAX_FUNCTION_NAME_LENGTH 1024


int printStackTrace()
{
    void *stack[TRACE_MAX_STACK_FRAMES];
    HANDLE process = GetCurrentProcess();
    SymInitialize(process, NULL, TRUE);
    WORD numberOfFrames = CaptureStackBackTrace(0, TRACE_MAX_STACK_FRAMES, stack, NULL);
    SYMBOL_INFO *symbol = (SYMBOL_INFO *)malloc(sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + (TRACE_MAX_FUNCTION_NAME_LENGTH - 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    symbol->MaxNameLen = TRACE_MAX_FUNCTION_NAME_LENGTH;
    symbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);
    DWORD displacement;
    IMAGEHLP_LINE64 *line = (IMAGEHLP_LINE64 *)malloc(sizeof(IMAGEHLP_LINE64));
    line->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(IMAGEHLP_LINE64);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFrames; i++)
    {
        DWORD64 address = (DWORD64)(stack[i]);
        SymFromAddr(process, address, NULL, symbol);
        if (SymGetLineFromAddr64(process, address, &displacement, line))
        {
            printf("\tat %s in %s: line: %lu: address: 0x%0X\n", symbol->Name, line->FileName, line->LineNumber, symbol->Address);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\tSymGetLineFromAddr64 returned error code %lu.\n", GetLastError());
            printf("\tat %s, address 0x%0X.\n", symbol->Name, symbol->Address);
        }
    }
    return 0;
} 

void* operator new(size_t size) {
    println("Allocated: " << size << " Bytes of memory");
    printStackTrace(); // add this
    return malloc(size);
}```
````